Documentation ANALYZE SAMPLE_SIZE 1000
Is there any more documentation on ANALYZE SAMPLE_SIZE ?
I would expect the higher the sample size the more accurate the result, however if I specify a large size (100000), the performance of my query drops by factor 10 or more.
I tried several values, also 0.

Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what you are asking. The accuracy of a sample and the performance of a query (how long it takes to run) are different things; so which one are you interested in? Obviously if your sample size is bigger then the query will take take longer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok, a little more context:
I do have a query that runs in about 2 seconds.
After only a few days, and minor data changes, the qurey runs in 2 minutes.
When I analyze the execution plan I see the order of the joins is changed by H2, I assume this is done by the optimizer.
From my understanding the optimizer uses the selectivity value to predict the optimal executution plan of the query.

So I read the documentation and try to understand how this selectivity is set, I found that the command ANALYZE SAMPLE_SIZE xxxx does do so. Then I tried this command with several sample_sizes and this has a huge impact on the permance of the query.
